# Simple Spring Boot Websocket client

Tags: spring, spring-boot, websocket

All is in the title, I can't find any piece of code on the web !

I just need a example of a websocket client to run under Spring Boot.

Thank you

Comment: I need a Java Client, I know this link, the client is in Javascript.
Moreover it's a Stomp server...

Comment: Have you already looked at https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/socket/client/standard/StandardWebSocketClient.html